# Erro ao fazer uma requisição POST com SpringBoot

Tags: java, api, spring-boot

Tenho o código abaixo:

```
String url = new StringBuilder().append("https://...").toString();
Map<String, Map<String, String>> body = buildBotBody(email,message);
restTemplate.postForEntity(url, body, Void.class);
```

Essa requisição não precisa de autenticação, ou seja não tem login e senha. Fazendo essa requisição no Postman funciona perfeitamente. Mas quando executo o código acima, obtenho o erro abaixo:

401 Unauthorized

Fiz outros testes e consegui simular o erro no Postman. Ele informou a mensagem abaixo:

```
"message": "The request has both SAS authentication scheme and 'Basic' authorization scheme. Only one scheme should be used."
```

Percebi que se eu mudar a forma de autenticação para “No Auth” no Postman, a requisição funciona.

Acho que no código teria que setar esse “No Auth” de alguma maneira.

---

Mais detalhes do código:

```
private HttpEntity<?> builderHeadersToBuildBotBody(String email, StringBuilder message) {
    
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("emailadress", email);
    map.put("emailSubject", "Pendência para lançamento de horas do Jira");
    map.put("emailBody", message.toString());
    
    return builderHeaders(map);
}

private HttpEntity<?> builderHeaders(Map<String, String> map) {
    
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    //requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application", "json")));
    requestHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "json"));
    //requestHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "");
    return new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);
}

private void sendBotMessage(StringBuilder message, String nome, String email) throws Exception{
    
    try {
        String url = new StringBuilder().append("https://prod-12.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/fbf4c29cbcad4679b1a1159fff7b07f9/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=zxm46aQnBj3ZTKPOddnnwUgtQZoQcQfixNtXVxAJjPg").toString();
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = builderHeadersToBuildBotBody(email,message);
        restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Void.class);
        logger.info("Bot enviado com sucesso! " + nome);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Erro ao enviar Bot.", e);
        throw e;
    }
    
}
```

Mas dessa forma também não funcionou.

Comment: Seu `restTemplate` não possui nenhuma configuração de interceptor para incluir um header de autorização ao realizar a chamada?

Comment: Vou mostrar acima como fiz usando cabeçalho.